# Where do malware typically hide in a Windows machine?

Tags: malware

Where can typical malware hide in a Windows machine? If not ran as an administrator, can they only hide in places where the UAC will not be triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Malware generally hides in folders that will be present across multiple machines, e.g. `C:\Windows` or `C:\Program Files`. Where it is able to hide depends on the program that initially placed the malware, and the permissions that it has.